# Python Telegram Bot. How to add a catch-all handler

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using library [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), and have some commands and message handlers added.
Message handlers are specific to the message, meaning there is a corresponding message handler for every commandhandler.
for example,

```
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("Start", self.start_cmd_callback))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile('Start', re.IGNORECASE)), self.start_msg_callback))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("Help", self.start_cmd_callback))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile('Help', re.IGNORECASE)), self.start_msg_callback))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("Set", self.start_cmd_callback))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile('Set', re.IGNORECASE)), self.start_msg_callback))
```

There are a few other command+message handlers like these.

Now the question is, how to add a catch-all handler, or a default fallback handler?
Since this is not a conversational bot, I want to fallback everything else (messages/commands) that is not a `command` or `alias message` to go to that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a MessageHandler that handles every single message, whatever the text is, then you can add (after every handler you already have) `MessageHandler(Filters.all, handle_everything_else)`.

If you want a different fallback handler for commands and messages then you might do something like

```py
MessageHandler(~Filters.command, handle_every_message)
MessageHandler(Filters.command, handle_every_command)
```

You can check the documentation of the filters [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html)